# Как сделать анимацию эффект рандома?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать анимацию? Надо прокрутить картинки 3 раза. А затем остановить на выбранной. Создать эффект случайного выпадения картинки. Как это можно реализовать?

```js
  var d =document.querySelector(".fortun");
function r() {
    run(2)
}
    function run(y) {
        var img =y*100;

        d.style.transform="translate(0px, -"+img+"px)";

    }
```

```css
 .con{
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .fortun{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
        }
        .use{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px
        }
```

```html
<div class="con" >
<div style="" class="fortun">
    <img class="use" src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Butterfly-PNG-6.png">
    <img class="use" src="https://img2.freepng.ru/20180228/bbw/kisspng-parrot-bird-blue-and-yellow-macaw-stock-photograph-parrot-bako-5a9659ccea79f5.9220246915198028289604.jpg">
    <img class="use" src="https://img2.freepng.ru/20180702/soa/kisspng-california-spangled-kitten-american-shorthair-euro-5b3aefa8c74863.7669235015305890968163.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="go" onclick="r()">
```

Comment: http://josex2r.github.io/jQuery-SlotMachine/ лень писать ответ сори

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Могу предложить вращать изображения вокруг оси x, вот что получается:

```js
let fortun = document.querySelectorAll('.fortun');
let angle = 0
function r() {
  fortun.forEach(f => {
      f.dataset.angle -= Math.floor(3+Math.random()*6)*120;
      f.querySelectorAll(".use").forEach(d => {
        d.style.setProperty('--r',  f.dataset.angle+'deg');
      });
  })
  setTimeout(e => {
    if (new Set([...fortun].map(f => (+f.dataset.angle / 120)%3)).size ===1)
      console.log('you win!')
  }, 2000)
}
```

```css
.fortun {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  perspective: 400px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:30px;
}

.use {
  transition:2s;
  position:absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  --r: 0deg;
  --t: 28.5px;
}

img.use:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateX(calc(0deg + var(--r))) translateZ(var(--t));
}
img.use:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateX(calc(120deg + var(--r))) translateZ(var(--t));
}
img.use:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateX(calc(240deg + var(--r))) translateZ(var(--t));
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="go" onclick="r()"><br>
<div style="" data-angle="120" class="fortun">
  <img class="use" src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/100/100">
  <img class="use" src="https://picsum.photos/id/22/100/100">
  <img class="use" src="https://picsum.photos/id/33/100/100">
</div>
<div style="" data-angle="0" class="fortun">
  <img class="use" src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/100/100">
  <img class="use" src="https://picsum.photos/id/22/100/100">
  <img class="use" src="https://picsum.photos/id/33/100/100">
</div>
<div style="" data-angle="120" class="fortun">
  <img class="use" src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/100/100">
  <img class="use" src="https://picsum.photos/id/22/100/100">
  <img class="use" src="https://picsum.photos/id/33/100/100">
</div>
```

Comment: а как сделать заместо кубов шары?

Comment: @Arcadiy как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: Вот такие шары с цифрами https://combinacii.ru/5_iz_36/

Comment: @Arcadiy можно, но не таким способом

Comment: Каким способом можно?

Comment: @Arcadiy а какой желаемый эффект? я бы предложил webgl

Comment: @StrangerintheQ мне оч. понравилось )) +1

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов да, забавно получилось, я даже сделал приколюху для кодепен-челлендж из этого https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/jONaJpX

Answer (score -2):

```js
let angle = 0
function r() {
  angle -= Math.floor(3+Math.random()*6)*120;
  document.querySelectorAll(".use").forEach(d => {
    d.style.setProperty('--r', angle+'deg');
  })
}
```

```css
.fortun {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  perspective: 400px;
  position:absolute;
  margin:30px;
}

.use {
  transition:2s;
  position:absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  --r: 0deg;
  --t: 28.5px;
}

img.use:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateX(calc(0deg + var(--r))) translateZ(var(--t));
}
img.use:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateX(calc(120deg + var(--r))) translateZ(var(--t));
}
img.use:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateX(calc(240deg + var(--r))) translateZ(var(--t));
}
```

```html
<div style="" class="fortun">
  <img class="use" src="https://picsum.photos/id/31/100/100" data-deg=33deg>
  <img class="use" src="https://picsum.photos/id/32/100/100">
  <img class="use" src="https://picsum.photos/id/33/100/100">
</div>

<input type="button" value="go" onclick="r()">
```

Comment: лол ) как ты ответ принял та)

Comment: а в чем прикол?:)

Comment: просто по фану лол